# Grease Pencil Sculpt Tools do not function

Tags: sculpting, grease-pencil

I have created a grease pencil design and want to sculpt it. However, no sculpt brushes seem to work. I have selected the grease pencil object before switching to sculpt mode. I can see the sculpt cursor and change the radius and strength.
Tried resetting all brushes but that does not help.
(Also tried copying and pasting the object in a new blend file, but still the same problem. New grease pencils can be sculpted though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the layer is protected (padlock on).

Check if the materials are protected.

Check if one of theese buttons is enabled (they limit the sculpt actions to selected points/strokes only).

[image]

Comment: As you suspected, one of the selection mask buttons was enabled. Turning it off did the trick. Thank you!